# Key value pair XML generation in Oracle APEX for BI Publisher report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, bi-publisher

In Oracle APEX, I am planning to have a report query which has the required SQL to populate a template developed in BI Publisher. I need a query that needs to generate an output which is similar to the XML mentioned below.

```
<DOCUMENT>
    <ROWSET>
      <PRIMARY_ID>10</PRIMARY_ID>
      <KEY_VALUE>
        <Key>Apple</Key>
        <Value>2</Value>
      </KEY_VALUE>
    </ROWSET>
    <ROWSET>
       <PRIMARY_ID>20</PRIMARY_ID>
       <KEY_VALUE>
        <Key>Orange</Key>
        <Value>5</Value>
       </KEY_VALUE>
    </ROWSET>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Please note that this query will be placed in "Report Query" section of Oracle APEX 5.1 version.

Currently, I was able to write an SQL query which could generate XML as below. The difference being there is NO "KEY_VALUE" tag enclosing the "Key" and "Value".

```
<DOCUMENT>
    <ROWSET>
      <PRIMARY_ID>10</PRIMARY_ID>
      <Key>Apple</Key>
      <Value>2</Value>
    </ROWSET>
    <ROWSET>
       <PRIMARY_ID>20</PRIMARY_ID>
       <Key>Orange</Key>
       <Value>5</Value>
    </ROWSET>
</DOCUMENT>
```

This is the query I came up with.

```
SELECT 
    distinct v.id id,
    (Select 'Status' from dual)  "KEY",
    (Select v.status from dual)  "Value"
FROM
    .......
```

Comment: Why do you need to add that additional XML Element/level? I assume you are only ever going to have one pair per ROWSET.

Comment: How does 'Status' turn into 'Apple' or 'Orange'? You say you were able to write a SQL query that generates the XML, but the Query you posted, doesn't seem to relate to the XML...

Comment: Hi All, Sorry, my bad. this is the query that I came up with

```
<DOCUMENT>
    <ROWSET>
      <PRIMARY_ID>10</PRIMARY_ID>
      <Key>Status</Key>
      <Value>Processed</Value>
    </ROWSET>
    <ROWSET>
       <PRIMARY_ID>20</PRIMARY_ID>
       <Key>Description</Key>
       <Value>Item 1</Value>
    </ROWSET>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Comment: Ya, that query shows that you are hard-coding each "key" to "status" in the SQL. I don't think you need to add another level either way.

Comment: @AshleshKumar you are saying "_this is the query I came up with_" and then you are pasting an XML format... And the query you posted in the original post, wouldn't lead to this XML either.

Comment: If you want a query that results in the first XML, post more information about the table structure and fields you need to query.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to come up with the Query that generates the output that I was expecting (I am sure there might be a better way, but with the time frames that I had this is the best that I could come up with, may be we can get some better solutions in this post).

I created a view with this SQL query below and used this view in Oracle APEX BI publisher.

```
Select * from 
    (SELECT PRIMARY_ID, 'Apple' as Key, item_count as value
     FROM xxc_test where item_id = 45
     UNION
     SELECT PRIMARY_ID, 'Orange' as Key, item_count as value
     FROM xxc_test where item_id = 46
     UNION
     SELECT PRIMARY_ID, 'Grapes' as Key, item_count as value
     FROM xxc_test where item_id = 47);
```